# use maemo camera by python

Tags: python, camera, gstreamer, maemo

I wrote a simple program for Maemo by Python to check some pixel's color every time that my function is called.  But this function runs very slowly (3-5 seconds each call).  Is there any faster way to do this?

```
import Image
import os
import sys

# sen_pos = (pixel_x, pixel_y)
def sen(sen_pos):
    os.system("gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! filesink location=cam.jpg")
    frame = Image.open("cam.jpg")
    col = frame.getpixel((sen_pos[0], sen_pos[1]))
    avecol = sum(col) / len(col)
    if avecol > 127:
        return "white"
    elif avecol < 127:
        return "black"
    return None
```

Comment: Without being at all familiar with gstreamer, is the colorspace conversion really necessary? Also, tuning the quality parameter to `jpegenc` may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an external program via `os.system` is likely what's taking the time.

Try using [GStreamer Python Bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) instead and keeping the video object around between calls. [The docs for Videomixer](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/videomixer.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

As George says, you may be incurring overhead in a system call but I suspect the `getpixel()` call. PIL's `getpixel()` is notoriously slow.  Instead [`load()`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) the image and then loop through -- that should be faster.